# How to implement autoscaling micro-service architecture without container orchestration?

Tags: microservices, autoscaling

can anyone tell/share the de-facto way of implementing auto-scaling in Spring Cloud utilized micro-service architecture? Assumption is no container orchestration such as Kubernetes, ECS, EKS. Expecting 2 separate answers in 2 below environments

1. In on-premise infra
2. In Cloud

Comment: Spring Cloud does not autoscaling. That is up to the platform.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to implement autoscaling by Spring Cloud which is only used to support microservice architecture. Basically, it is the question how to implement autoscaling without container orchestration